# I was denied a US visa in March 2018 and I want to reapply

Tags: visas

I was denied a US visa in March under 214b. I was attending a UN conference and I was not asked for any supporting documents. Yet I had them. I want to apply again for a conference in October. What should I do?

And how should I present myself to show strong ties with my country?

Comment: What ties do you have? Job, savings, property, family...?

Comment: In six months what can you use to show your circumstances have changed significantly? 214b means they're not convinced you will not stay permanently in the USA.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Here are my ties to my home country. Do you think they are enough? How can I prove them?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/72007/here-are-my-ties-to-my-home-country-do-you-think-they-are-enough-how-can-i-pro), and [B1/B2 US tourist visa refusal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/95866/b1-b2-us-tourist-visa-refusal), and [How to prove that you have significant ties with family in your home country](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103826/how-to-prove-that-you-have-significant-ties-with-family-in-your-home-country)

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify comments, putting on hold